# Standard practice for the pattern of updating a field when another one updates

Tags: clojure

Suppose you have two values `x` and `y` such that `y` should be computed every time `x` is updated. In Java, everything is an object so I have little choice. The way to do it would be via a class, e.g.

```java
public Data {
   private type x, y;

   Data(type x) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = null;
   }
   
   void updateX(type2 val) {
      // perform operation to update X
      // perform (expensive) operation to update Y
   }
   
   void getX() {...}
   void getY() {...}
}
```

In clojure, a direct translation of this might use `deftype` and `defprotocol`/`definterface`. But that's too much for just defining a dependency between two variables. In particular, I have an objection to giving it a name and treating it on par with actual types and protocols.

I know this is what `defrecord`s are for -- when you need to make a class that does not represent an entity in the business domain, but then `defrecord`s are immutable.

Do I have other choices? I had a look at `RxClojure` because the situation here seems to be "reactive", but that seems to be oriented toward "emit"-ing events rather than e.g. just storing the latest one in an atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use [add-watch](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch) facility for that. For example:

```
(defn entangle [x-val computation]
  (let [x (atom x-val)
        y (atom (computation x-val))]
    (add-watch x nil (fn [_ _ old-x new-x]
                       (reset! y (computation new-x))))
    {:x x
     :y y}))
```

In the above example `y` value depends on `x` value through the `computation` function.

```
(let [{:keys [x y]} (entangle 10 #(* % %))]
  (println "x:" @x "y:" @y)
  (swap! x inc)
  (println "x:" @x "y:" @y)
  (reset! x 200)
  (println "x:" @x "y:" @y))

;; x: 10 y: 100
;; x: 11 y: 121
;; x: 200 y: 40000
nil
```

This could be handy in some situations, though generally such tangled code eliminates referential transparency, and i would probably avoid using it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I agree that this could be confusing, but I think the confusion could be managed (certainly not eliminated) by putting both the refs in an object (as you do at the return of `entangle`), and users of the code being aware that this is a special "reactive" object, perhaps not even trying to separate the refs into different variables as you did in the `let`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but think that you're overthinking this.

```
(def some-var (atom some-value))

(def derived (atom (some-expensive-fn some-var)))

(defn update-derived
  [old-state new-state]
  (new-state)

(defn update-var
  [x]
  (swap! derived 
         update-derived 
         (swap! some-var (fn [old-state] (x)))))
```

We define some state, some derived state, and a function that takes a new value and updates both.

## Edit based on comment

If you want to be able to do this multiple times you can use a factory that returns a closure:

```
(defn make-stateful-thing-with-derived-value
  [init-x-value compute-y]
  (let [x (atom init-x-value)
        y (atom (compute-y init-x-value))]
    (list x
          y
          (fn [new-x-value]
            (swap! y
                   (fn [old-s] (compute-y new-x-value))
                   (swap! x (fn [old-s] (new-x-value)))))))
```

The function takes an initial x value and a function to derive y and returns a list with the atoms x and y and a function that accepts a value to update them.

Comment: Ah. But unlike a class or record which can be instantiated multiple times, this would be limited to two specific variables in the program. Imagine the same functionality, but parametrized over `some-var` and `derived`

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Check my updated answer. Typed it in SO not an editor, so parens may not balance at the end but you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Using a closure to have the independent entities (update function, x, y) be able to share a common state is useful, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha I see from your profile that you're a web dev. You can do the same thing in Javascript: `(init, f) => { let x = init; let y = f(x); return [x, y, (update) => { x = update; y = f(x); }]}`

Comment: Yep. But I didn't know that I could do closures in clojure!